# add user entered data to database using jsf

Tags: jsf-2

As I'm new to JSF framework, wanted to know how to add the user entered data to the database.
More clearly, i'm using jsf with jsp, my jsp contains some input fields and a submit button.How do i capture all the user entered data and send it as input paramters for the button, as my back end takes all these as input parameters and updates the table with a new record.

Please look into my code and lety me know my mistake

### Registration.jsp

```
<body>
 <f:view>
  <h:form>
           <h:panelGrid columns="2" rules="all" width="100%" style="background:#03547C;color:#FDD017">
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Stu No : "></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText value="#{RegBean.stuNo}"/>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Stu Name : "></h:outputText>
                    <h:inputText value="#{RegBean.stuName}"/>
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                      <h:outputText value="Standard : "></h:outputText>
                      <h:inputText value="#{RegBean.standard}" />
                 </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                       <h:outputText value="School : "></h:outputText>
                       <h:inputText value="#{RegBean.school}" />
                 </h:column>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" rules="all" width="100%" style="background:#03547C;color:#FDD017">
                <h:column>
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" action="#{RegBean.submitDetails}">
                            <f:param name="sNo" value="#{RegBean.stuNo}" />
                            <f:param name="sName" value="#{RegBean.stuName}" />
                            <f:param name="std" value="#{RegBean.standard}" />
                            <f:param name="schl" value="#{RegBean.school}" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
                </h:column>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</body>
```

### Registration Bean

```
public class VendorRegBean {
private String stuNo;
private String stuName;
private String standard;
private String school;

  // getters and setters

    public void submitDetails() {
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
      String stNo = (String) requestMap.get("sNo");
      String stName = (String) requestMap.get("sName");
      String stndrd = (String) requestMap.get("std");
      String scl = (String) requestMap.get("schl");
    vReg.stuRegistration(stNo ,stName ,stndrd ,scl );        
}
```

}

Comment: The entire JEE6 software stack is available at Oracle. Unfortunately, Oracle forces you to d/l Glassfish 3.1 (the JEE6 reference implementation), but you don't have to set it up, just install the binary. Then put [root]/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/javaee.jar in your build or class path. It contains everything you need for JSF development. Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get the parameters from the request parameter map as long as you register your bean as managed bean and provide getter and setter methodes for your bean members.

Use annotations for your bean to declare it as managed bean. Getter and setter example are given for `stuNo` member:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class RegBean {
      private String stuNo;
      ...


      private String getStuNo() {
        return stuNo;
      }

      private String setStuNo(String stuNo) {
        this.stuNod = stuNo;
      }
    }
```

In the view you have to reference the managed bean with first letter lower case, such as:

```
<h:inputText value="#{regBean.stuNo}"/>
```

Your command button doesn't need `<f:param>`, simply use:

```
<h:commandButton id="submitBtn" value="Submit" action="#{regBean.submitDetails}"/>
```

Then all parameters are automatically available in your `submitDetails` method and you don't need to get them from the parameter map.

Comment: can you suggest me the jar file which includes javax.faces.bean.*; because when i dont have the related lib files for this and i didn't find it on google too...pls helkp me in finding the respective jar file

Comment: You need _jsf-api.jar_ and _js-impl.jar_ (e.g. from [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html)] but since you are using the jsf tags your should have them already in your classpath, or am I missing something?

Comment: i have those 2 jars in my class path but still i'm unable to use javax.faces.bean.*;that was my doubt.... also thanks a lot for the above answer, I dint know the parameters are available directly.

Comment: can u also suggest me how to generate a popup window in the same context...once my database is updated withe user enterd data i want to show a popup displaying "registration successfull" and also display a reg ID(from database)